# WPML doesn't show translated languages of the YITH default text (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, translation, wpml

I translated defalult text of the YITH plugn (Request a quote plugin) in the WPML String.
But it only shows English in the frontend.
*Other strings show translated languages, just this part doesn't show translated languages.
Would you please let me know how to solve this issue?
YITH plugin:
[image]

WPML String:
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a regression or a bug. Last time this plugin was tested by the WPML team:

> Version 1.7.7

> Last tested on: July 4, 2017

https://wpml.org/plugin/yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote/

I suggest you post a ticket on the support forum: https://wpml.org/forums/forum/english-support/

Comment: Also they have a troubleshooting article that seems to fit what you're experiencing: https://wpml.org/faq/why-arent-my-translated-strings-showing-up-on-the-front-end-of-my-site/